# How to : update fontawesome with bower

Tags: icons, npm, updates, bower, font-awesome

I can see on FontAwesome GitHub that a new version 4.2 has been release

I use bower 1.3.9 (latest), and my current version of font awesome is 4.1

When I type `bower update fontawesome` or `bower update fontawesome#4.2` I can't get the 4.2.

Is there a way to update font awesome to 4.2 with bower ?

Into the bower.json of fontawesome bower components directory, I can see this git url  `git://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.git` which is slightly the same as https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.git where the latest version is available.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I have edited my `bower.json` file and replaced the line:

```
"fontawesome": "~4.1.0",
```

with:

```
"fontawesome": "https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.git#~4.2.0"
```

Finally, I did `bower install fontawesome --save`.

It finally updated font awesome.

```
bower cached        https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.git#4.2.0
bower validate      4.2.0 against https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.git#~4.2.0
bower cached        git://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.git#4.1.0
bower validate      4.1.0 against git://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.git#*
bower new           version for git://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.git#*
bower resolve       git://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.git#*
bower download      https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/archive/v4.2.0.tar.gz
bower extract       fontawesome#* archive.tar.gz
bower resolved      git://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.git#4.2.0
bower install       fontawesome#4.2.0
```

I have reopened my bower.json, my line has been replaced by:

```
"fontawesome": "~4.2.0",
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Good to see you solved your initial problem, but I think the real problem here was related to `semver`. If the version you intended to install was not "approximately equivalent" (`~`) to the version you had specified on your `bower.json` file, you wouldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 7):

I think you can also simply run:

```
/var/shared/bower> bower install font-awesome#4.3.0 --save
font-awesome#4.3.0 bower_components/font-awesome
```

It will replace the current font-awesome version with the new one.
( it won't create a new dir )

Comment: at the time I wrote, this solution wasn't working, even if 4.2.0 was release on github

Comment: I know, I just thought of placing a comment for others who see this, because I was struggling with this myself and found your post ..:)

Answer (score 1):

Please add following line to your bower.json file

"components-font-awesome": "~4.5.0"

then run a "bower install" command on your command line.

Comment: Where is the difference between "font-awesome" and "components-font-awesome" and which of those should be preferred?